# How to make a continuous sheet in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I remove the strip between the pages? I have to turn all pages into one long endless page. The thing I want to make has to look like the 'Draft' view mode with images.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**To view the document as one continuous page without page separators:**

Under the `View` tab switch to `Web Layout`. Note that your document's width will be "elastic" in this view, meaning your paragraphs will stretch to fill as much width as they are given (try resizing the window).

**To change the appearance of the page separator in Print Layout:**

Place your mouse pointer exactly on the separator line and double click. This toggles the display of white space between pages.

Comment: but if you do that, save to pdf will still have pages.

Comment: @v.oddou The OP asked about Word, not about saving to a PDF. If that's the problem you're facing I would suggest posting a new question. Also, if someone gives you a PDF with separate pages you can usually set the view mode to make it seem continuous. For example, in Adobe Reader XI, go to View > Page Display and uncheck "Show Gaps Between Pages".

Comment: This doesn't allow a collaborator to see the view the same way. They still see pages. There must be some way to collaborate on what is essentially a web like view instead of defined pages, especially when a document would never be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Double click to remove the space (replaced with small gray line) and the change your margins to custom and use 0" top and bottom. Looks pretty close to continuous. Otherwise the web view works as well (I don't like the width so I always manually change it to the standard 8.5" using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl-A just select the text?  How does it change the width?