# Web layout with margins in Microsoft Word or LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, margins, writing

In any word processor, is there any way to restrict the width of the web layout view to a comfortable width for reading and writing? I understand that you could simply make the GUI window narrower but I was hoping for a less distracting option.

Another way to achieve a similar affect would be to have "continuous pages" in page layout view but that question has already been asked here: [How to make a continuous sheet in MS Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1124335/how-to-make-a-continuous-sheet-in-ms-word). Note that hiding white space between pages is not a solution to this since elements (think images) may not lay between page boundaries which causes ugly gaps in the continuous text.

I get frustrated that word processors are so focused on page layout.

Comment: I have submitted a feature request for this to LibreOffice Writer: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118028

Comment: You might want to consider using a maybe unexpected Option: Microsoft's WordPad. It doesn't display pages at all, you get a continuous vertical space, but a restricted width that can be adjusted py changing the paper format in the page setup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Microsoft Office Button Button image, and then click Word Options.

Click Proofing.

Under AutoCorrection settings, click AutoCorrect Options, and then click the 
AutoFormat As You Type tab.

Uncheck the Set left- and first-indent with tabs and backspaces check box.

Then go to layout and then indent. Add 2" to left and 2" to right