# How to turn off page breaks in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to turn off page breaks in MS Word.  To be clear, I don't want to remove a particular break, or reposition a break, I want to entirely disable the concept of pages altogether.  I do not intend to print anything that I create in MS Word, basically ever under any circumstances.  So, there is no need for pages, and the page breaks force a very weird flow and layout into a document that is designed to be consumed electronically.

Is it possible to turn off "pages" in MS Word?  If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can also set the defaults for layout: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-settings-for-new-documents-430b4132-e129-46e4-97d2-19c326352c7f

Comment: You can't switch off "pages"but you might be able to work in Web Layout view which doesn't "do" pagination (e.g. { PAGE } fields are evaluated as 1). But that may mean the loss of familiar features. Also, you will probably need to save as HTML to prevent Word repaginating whenever it wants to. There are some other suggestions at https://superuser.com/questions/1124335/how-to-make-a-continuous-sheet-in-ms-word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word 2016 - that’s the latest I have access to - there’s a “mode switcher” in the lower right hand corner. The image below shows the “normal” setting with pagination, the left icon is “read mode”m which shows two pages side-by-side, like a book, and the right icon is “web layout” mode, which eliminates pagination. Note that your document isn’t stored with the automatic page breaks; the text is continuous, and Word will compute where page breaks should be based on such things as paper size and margins.

[image: The mode indicator for Word 2016]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with MS Word, but here are two alternatives to achieve this:

##### OneNote

[OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/) is another Microsoft product which you could use. On OneNote, you can create notebooks (files) which can contain different sections with sites. You can style a site with many options and there are no pages like in Word. It's like a whiteboard with advanced features.

##### Google Docs

[Google Docs](https://www.google.com/docs/about/) is the MS Word made by Google. There you can create a document and [enable the pageless option](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/11528737?hl=en).

Comment: This is very definitely possible with Word; see my answer.

Comment: This is the answer OP needs, though it may not be the one they want. Word is about pages. That is a core aspect of its nature. While you can use Web View or save html files or various other things, the design and function of Word is based around the idea of Pages. OneNote is designed around the concept of NOT pages. Its function is anti-page.